# How to model a Navigation Drawer menu on a list of objects?

Tags: android

My Android application has a navigation drawer. I want to populate the navigation drawer menu by user-defined entries. A user-defined entry is modeled by a class:

```
data class Location(val name: String, val data: Int)
```

When a menu entry is clicked, I want to call a method accepting a `Location` corresponding to the clicked menu entry. The best idea I had is keep the model as a `List<Location>` (this list will ultimately be loaded from a database) and populate the menu in `onCreate`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private val toolbar by lazy { findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar) }
    private val drawerLayout by lazy { findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawerLayout) }
    private val navigationView by lazy { findViewById<NavigationView>(R.id.navigation) }

    private val savedLocations = listOf(Location("foo", 42), Location("bar", 1337))

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        // Connect the action bar and the navigation drawer
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawerOpen, R.string.drawerClose)
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()

        // Handle clicks in the navigation drawer
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

        // Populate the navigation drawer
        populateDrawer()
    }

    override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // ...
        return true
    }

    fun loadLocation(location: Location) {
        // application logic here
    }

    private fun populateDrawer() {
        for (location in savedLocations) {
            navigationView.menu.add(location.name)
        }
    }
}
```

In `onNavigationItemSelected` I'd like to do something like

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    val i = item.getIndex();
    loadLocation(savedLocations[i])
    return true
}
```

However, it appears that `MenuItem` doesn't know its index. What I could do is to manually specify the `itemId` like this:

```kotlin
savedLocations.forEachIndexed { index, location ->
     // set itemId = index for every MenuItem
     navigationView.menu.add(0, index, 0, location.name)
}
```

where `i` is the iteration index.
But this is getting hacky, because `MenuItem.NONE == 0`.

Is there any better solution or is the Android convention to use a different pattern here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to use a `RecyclerView` or `ListView` instead of a `NavigationView`.